# div colors on image

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

I have this image where i have placed small divs above it. when a user click on a div the color of the div changes from blue to red and inserts a value to database with the div id.

My questions are

1. How shall i retain the color of the div after clicked when the page gets refresh. I can call the database and check for each divs but somehow i felt it is not the best method
2. I have set  **position:absolute;left:80px;top:21px;** for each divs. I want to know is there any other better method to this as I have to make one more image with same functionality for every user

Please help me to find a solution

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhdstrong textzi.png

thanking you all in advance

I have not been allowed to add image here so temporarily i am sharing the image from my local system

Comment: my presumption here is that when you click the div to add the value to the db you are posting back and so the page reloads?

Comment: not actually i am not posting the value back i am just changing the color of it when clicked and inserting the details of the div into db. But when user refresh the page i have to check with db for that particular div id. in order to do this i wanted to know the best method

Comment: are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: so you are storing the div details as a record in the db so that on subsequent visits the user gets the customized view, correct? If that is the case I agree with @NappingRabbit, there really is no other way to persist those values other than put them a DB. You are doing it the same way the rest of us do. Can you clarify the second part of your question?

Comment: yes i am storing the div details with user id. I have around 30 divs over an image so does that means i have to call the db as many times. For the second question the image with 30 divs may be repeated. so that means 60 divs i have to set position statically

Comment: I get it now. I would suggest finding a way to store the 30 divs as a single object. Then you make a single call instead of 30. you could store the values for the divs by name value pair in a delimited string: div1^red,div2^green,etc

Comment: 403 forbidden is all I get with that link

Comment: http://124.125.231.11/marktest/  Please reply if you able to view it

Comment: I see the image now. It looks like you can't optimize that. You are making a map of that image with the divs. I would maybe suggest an alternate way of doing this. You can make an image map out of the image and then when one is clicked use jQuery to add a div over that part of the map. Then store only the added divs. that would make less to store and retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Pow-lan. I was looking around for the best way of doing it. Yours is also a very good suggestion

Comment: Hi I just wanted to share what I did. For checking if the div is already clicked              $(document).ready(function(){

 $.post("ajaxfunctions.php",{"case":'first'},function(data){
   
   for(var i =0;i < data.length;i++)
   {
     var item = data[i];
     $("#blue"+item).removeClass('blueColor');
     $("#blue"+item).addClass('redColor');
   
   }
   
   },'json')
})

Answer (score 0):

To change color when clicked

```
<div onclick="changeColor()" id="demo">


function changeColor(){
document.getElementById("demo").style.background="red";
}
```

Colors can be stored in the database

Comment: Using localStorage wouldn't make sense in this situation. What if someone uses their account on two computers? I would just check the database and append a class to change the div to red if it's been clicked.

Comment: color change i am able to do it what i want to know is retaining the changed color when i refresh the page. there are random divs around 30 in number

Comment: are all the divs of the same color ?

Comment: initially it is the same when clicked a div the color of that div will be changed. that color should be retain when a user login. this is how i have done to check if div has been clicked  $(document).ready(function(){

 $.post("ajaxfunctions.php",{"case":'first'},function(data){
   
   for(var i =0;i < data.length;i++)
   {
     var item = data[i];
     $("#blue"+item).removeClass('blueColor');
     $("#blue"+item).addClass('redColor');
   
   }
   
   },'json')
})

Comment: why dont you sent the color and save it into the database when the user logs out. Fetch this value when user logs in. Use a value as default

Answer (score 0):

1. That is the only real solution (storing and retrieving values) if you want to save the selected value for a period of time; it will also accommodate a refresh.
2. This is a fine solution, but it forces you to calculate the position for each new user if I understand correctly.  You may consider floating container divs and positioning the absolute divs inside them accordingly.

Comment: second suggestion sounds good to me..can you please give me a sample code...as i am little weak in designing...thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I am sorry, I am at work and can not open your page to see your specific situation.